# Why cant we use AllowedValues for key pair as String using the Parameter in CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

Recently I have Started learning Cloud Formation using YAML. I have key pairs as **CFNkey, Newkey1, Newkey2**. [**Here is an image**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wke70.jpg). So my doubt is if I am trying to use a Type as String for keypairs I am getting [**this error message**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6929.jpg). The YAML code I have used is as follows:-

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: Parameter using the Dynamic KeyName
Parameters: 
  MyKeyName:
    Description: Select the key Name from the below 
    Type: String
    Default: Newkey1
    AllowedValues:
     - CFNkey
     - Newkey2
Resources:
 DevEC2Instance:
  Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
  Properties:
   InstanceType: t2.micro
   ImageId: ami-04aa88aebb9fefd83
   KeyName: !Ref MyKeyName 
   SecurityGroup:
    - !Ref SSHSecurityGroup
 SSHSecurityGroup:
  Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup 
  Properties: 
  GroupDescription: My Sg
  SecurityIngress:
    IpProtocol: tcp
    ToPort: 22
    FromPort: 22
    Cidr: 0.0.0.0/0
  SecurityEgress:
    IpProtocol: tcp 
    ToPort: 8080
    FromPort: 8080
    Cidr: 0.0.0.0/0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Newkey1` must be listed in `AllowedValues`:

```
  MyKeyName:
    Description: Select the key Name from the below 
    Type: String
    Default: Newkey1
    AllowedValues:
     - Newkey1
     - CFNkey
     - Newkey2
```